# three.js tube with variable radius

Tags: three.js

I am attempting to draw a tube along a path and the TubeGeometry object seemed to be made for this. However, there's a catch - I also want the radius to be variable along each point of the path. Basically, I'm trying to draw a variable width tube.

I can draw this using multiple tubes and cylinders, but I can't help but think there's got to be a better way.

Comment: Is the tube straight? If so, use `THREE.LatheGeometry`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Well, then, you can hack `TubeGeometry.js` to accept a variable radius as a function of distance along the path.

Answer (score 7):

WestLangley's suggestion works well. I ended up creating a class based on THREE.TubeGeometry with the following modifications (R59):

1. Modified constructor parameter radius to take an array of numbers representing the radius at each control point.
2. Modified code as shown below (introduced posRadius variable and substituted for radius):

```
    for (i = 0; i < numpoints; i++) {
        this.grid[i] = [];

        u = i / (numpoints - 1);

        pos = path.getPointAt(u); 
        var posRadius = this.radius[Math.floor((this.radius.length - 1) * u)];

        tangent = tangents[i];
        normal = normals[i];
        binormal = binormals[i];

        for (j = 0; j < this.radialSegments; j++) {

            v = j / this.radialSegments * 2 * Math.PI;
            // TODO: Hack: Negating it so it faces outside.
            cx = -posRadius * Math.cos(v); 
            cy = posRadius * Math.sin(v);

            pos2.copy(pos);
            pos2.x += cx * normal.x + cy * binormal.x;
            pos2.y += cx * normal.y + cy * binormal.y;
            pos2.z += cx * normal.z + cy * binormal.z;

            this.grid[i][j] = vert(pos2.x, pos2.y, pos2.z);

        }
    }
```